# memory allocation - Java vs C++

Tags: java, c++, memory, heap-memory

Given class Line in both java and C++, and the following declarations in java and C++ respectively -

```
Line[] p;
```

and

```
Line *p;
```

What are the differences in semantics between the two languages when then running the following code:

```
p = new Line[7];
```

In particular, do both languages assign heap memory for the array in the same way?

Sorry I done research on this matter, however i still feel i have not completely understood.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When arrays are declared in Java, they are stored as an array of references. You wouldn't run into this overhead cost when initializing an array of the `Line` class in C++ because your array will hold the objects, not merely their references.

Comment: This gets important when allocating multidimensional arrays. While C++ allocates all dimensions as one large chunk of memory, Java scatters the sub-arrays. For a 10x10 array of `int`s, for examle, Java allocates 10 arrays of size `10 * size of int + a little` plus one array of size `10 * size of reference + a little`, C++ only allocates one array of size `100 * size of int`. The `a little` is needed in Java for additional information: size of the array, type, ...

Comment: Yes, great point and exactly right Turing85! :O) Attaching 2-D memory allocation ref for C++ (http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/23two-dim-array-memory-layout.html) and Java (http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/array_memory_usage.shtml) for OP

Comment: @user3636636 The code above will create an array of seven references. Those references will be set to `null`. You can verify that by iterating over the array and printing the entries after `new Line[7];`. Both arrays (in C++ and Java) are initialized with `null` since neither C++ nor Java "knows" how to initialize a line. The situation is different with build-ins (`int`, `long`, ...) since they have propper default values. Furhtermore, C++ uses "in-place" arrays: the arrays store the entries direclty, whereas the java-array "only" stores the reference to an object.

Comment: @Turing85: For an array of objects, C++ will require a default constructor, so it *does* know how to initialize a 'Line' - C++ will initialize it according to the default constructor.

Comment: This answer is somewhat problematic. While stating the difference in semantics between the two snippets is great (and it's the essence of this whole question), mentioning an overhead for reference/pointer arrays (versus value arrays) is *very* misleading without context. I have seen ridiculously wrong *and* inefficient C and C++ code (in the order of hundreds megabytes of memory completely wasted) by people who were blindly trying to eliminate this "overhead cost" because they heard about it somewhere else without context.

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing Java and C++ code that is not equivalent.
The following C++ is the equivalent of your Java code (array of references):

```
Line **p;
p = new Line*[7];
```

The C++ version you posted:

```
Line *p;
p = new Line[7];
```

is an array of objects and initializes each element of the array using the default constructor of 'Line' (try it with an explicit 1-parameter constructor and you'll see that C++ tells you that you need a default constructor). Java has no equivalent to this way of creating arrays of non-primitive types that get each element default-constructed - in Java all elements of a non-primitive type array are 'null' until you explicitly assign them).

Answer (score 0):

As said above, the equivilant C++ code is actually

```
Line **p;
p = new Line*[7];
```

since Java allocate an array of references, not array of ad-hoc objects.

In C++, the `new` operator is guarenteed to allocat memory from the heap.
In Java - it depends. usually the `new` keyword allocate memory from the heap, but some compilers, such as HotSpot preform what is called "escape analysis" : if the compiler detects that a pointer is not returned from a function, nor going to different thread - it *may* declare the object in the stack (equivilant to `Line p[7]` C++)